# arcpy.AddGeometryAttributes_management throws error: error in executing tool

Tags: arcpy

I am trying to add XY extents to point and line features using the `arcpy.AddGeometryAttributes_management` tool, but it throws an error:

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-13-6497264af48f> in <module>()
     65 """
     66 #this is failing, but don't know why...
---> 67 arcpy.AddGeometryAttributes_management(in_features, properties)#, length_unit, area_unit, coordinate_system)
     68 
     69 #take first point, search for line with same min/max extent as point AND next point (thus in between points)


C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py in AddGeometryAttributes(Input_Features, Geometry_Properties, Length_Unit, Area_Unit, Coordinate_System)    1977         return retval    1978     except Exception as e:
-> 1979         raise e    1980     1981 @gptooldoc('AddXY_management', None)

C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py in AddGeometryAttributes(Input_Features, Geometry_Properties, Length_Unit, Area_Unit, Coordinate_System)    1974     from arcpy.arcobjects.arcobjectconversion import convertArcObjectToPythonObject    1975     try:
-> 1976         retval = convertArcObjectToPythonObject(gp.AddGeometryAttributes_management(*gp_fixargs((Input_Features, Geometry_Properties, Length_Unit, Area_Unit, Coordinate_System), True)))    1977         return retval    1978     except Exception as e:

C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py in <lambda>(*args)
    494         val = getattr(self._gp, attr)
    495         if callable(val):
--> 496             return lambda *args: val(*gp_fixargs(args, True))
    497         else:
    498             return convertArcObjectToPythonObject(val)

RuntimeError: Object: Error in executing tool
```

My code:

```
in_features = "points_backup"#, "lines_backup"] 

properties = "EXTENT"
length_unit = ""
area_unit = ""
coordinate_system = ""

arcpy.AddGeometryAttributes_management(in_features, properties)#, length_unit, area_unit, coordinate_system)
```

I commented out the length, area and coord sys as they are optional.  This is near verbatim to the example code ESRI gives in the documentation of the `AddGeometryAttributes_management` (http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/add-geometry-attributes.htm)

Update: I changed my original post to make `in_features` a single feature class instead of a list of feature classes-this resolve that original issue, but now I get the error:

```
ExecuteError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-c84e1f2e998a> in <module>()
     65 """
     66 #this is failing, but don't know why...
---> 67 arcpy.AddGeometryAttributes_management(in_features, properties)#, length_unit, area_unit, coordinate_system)
     68 
     69 #take first point, search for line with same min/max extent as point AND next point (thus in between points)

C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py in AddGeometryAttributes(Input_Features, Geometry_Properties, Length_Unit, Area_Unit, Coordinate_System)
   1977         return retval
   1978     except Exception as e:
-> 1979         raise e
   1980 
   1981 @gptooldoc('AddXY_management', None)

C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py in AddGeometryAttributes(Input_Features, Geometry_Properties, Length_Unit, Area_Unit, Coordinate_System)
   1974     from arcpy.arcobjects.arcobjectconversion import convertArcObjectToPythonObject
   1975     try:
-> 1976         retval = convertArcObjectToPythonObject(gp.AddGeometryAttributes_management(*gp_fixargs((Input_Features, Geometry_Properties, Length_Unit, Area_Unit, Coordinate_System), True)))
   1977         return retval
   1978     except Exception as e:

C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py in <lambda>(*args)
    494         val = getattr(self._gp, attr)
    495         if callable(val):
--> 496             return lambda *args: val(*gp_fixargs(args, True))
    497         else:
    498             return convertArcObjectToPythonObject(val)
```

> ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid. ERROR
>   000800: The value is not a member of Point x-, y-, z-, and
>   m-coordinates. Failed to execute (AddGeometryAttributes).

The `in_feature` `'points_backup'` is a Point feature class ('enterprise geodatabase Feature Class'), with no Z or M, but I only need to add extent fields (min/max X/Y).  This feature is not registered as versioned or enabled archive, if that matters.

Comment: You're using Iron Python aren't you? Is this being run from within Iron Python or from an Esri python console (or DOS/CMD)?

Comment: I am currently running it from Jupyter Notebooks (there is currently an issue and cannot use IDLE-I ultimately want this to be a stand alone script I can call) but I am seeing the same error in the python window from within ArcGIS Pro as well.

Comment: It looks like you need to iterate your features (for thisFC in in_features: then substitute thisFC for in_features in your tool) as this tool accepts a single input and not a list of feature classes or layers. However your in_features list looks like layers and not proper feature classes, if you want to run this in CMD you will either need to set your environment workspace to where the in_features are or use the full path.

Comment: I reduced the in_features to be just a single feature class (in_features = ["points_backup"]) and got a different error (saying my point fc is not a member of Point x-, y-, z-, and m-coordinates???), so that must have been the original issue: you cannot pass in multiple feature classes to that tool (unless like Michael said, you loop through a list of them, and hand them in separately).

Comment: in_features = ["points_backup"] is still a list of one object. Can you edit your question and post your updated code please.

Comment: I edited my original post, and changed my code to reflect Michael's suggestion, which resolved that first error.  I'm still faced with that second error.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got this function working for both features I was trying to add the geometry features to.  The original issue was that i was handing in a list when I needed to loop through the in_features list, the second issue was that a point feature and a line feature need to use different properties, which add different geometry fields to the feature classes:

## Add geometry attributes to points and lines

```py
arcpy.AddGeometryAttributes_management(db_and_owner + 'points_backup', 'POINT_X_Y_Z_M')
arcpy.AddGeometryAttributes_management(db_and_owner + 'tmp_lines_split', 'EXTENT')
```

I got rid of the property assignments and put the properties directly in the call to the function, and made two separate functions since they need different 'property' values.

For points, this adds POINT_X, and POINT_Y fields, and for lines it adds EXT_MIN_X, EXT_MIN_Y, EXT_MAX_X, and EXT_MAX_Y fields (http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/add-geometry-attributes.htm)